# SQL c# determining type of sql server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

Does anyone know of a good way, programmatically, to determine if a sql server is a mysql or mssql installation?

I've got an app in c# that has to be able to connect to either mysql or mssql. I can connect to either if I know which it is, but I can't tell from the connection settings because all I get are the server name, userid, password, and database name.

I can have the settings file store the type of server, but this opens up an avenue for user error that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: `select version()`. that'll work on mysql, and give you a version number. mssql equivalent `select @@version`. neither should work on the opposite system.

Comment: Workaround: Use a try/catch block. Try to open with SQL Server drivers and if it fails, try to open with mySQL drivers. Flip these around to catch the most common type of connection first.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? If it is user authentication you can tell from the connection string. MySql = UID and Sql Server = User ID

Comment: He can connect to both MSSQL and mysql with ODBC.

Comment: So you're saying you cannot trust your end-user to pick the correct RDBMS system via a listbox?  Wowsers.  Yep, the answer of "try to connect with 1...then the other" answer is all you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to connect as MySQL and if it fails, handle the error gracefully then try to connect as MSSQL.  Something loosely similar to this might work for you ...

```
string FindDbType(string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        // try to connect with MySql
        return "MySql";
    } catch()
    {
        try
        {
            // try to connect with MSSQL
            return "MSSql";
        } catch()
        {
            return "Cannot determine DB Type"
        }
    }   
}
```

You will probably want to handle errors like incorrect password separately, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Create table like `config` or `settings` and put there record for DB type. (If DB which you access is yours.)

Comment: jboeke you've got the most useful answer but I'd prefer to do it without doing a fail test.  For the other answers, like I said in my post, I don't get a connection string, just a userid, password, servername, and database name.  There's no connection string to decode because my code builds it;   And select version() works fine if you're already connected to the server.